# Trigonometric function based sum

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A+B=45$, then show that $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)=2$.

Please show all the steps, and explain how to solve this. I tried to solve this by multiplying both sides by tan but couldn't proceed further

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to give a full solution yet, since I want to give you a chance to give it a go.

**Hint:**

Use
$$\tan(A+B)=\tan(45^\circ)=1=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$$ Note that $$(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)=1+\tan A+\tan B+\tan A \tan B$$
Then try to rearrange the first equation so that it gives $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)$.

Comment: To be overly precise: 

We need to restrict this to when tan is defined. Both this answer and the original question. We can't have this result when $A=90$ and $B=-45$.

My point is that $A+B=45$ doesn't imply that $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)$ exists.

Comment: @Mason I don't feel it is really worth adding to the answer, since the person who asked the question probably does not care about these cases (when $A$ or $B = \frac{2n+1}2\pi$) when they ask the question. But, yes it is useful to have this comment for the sake of future readers.

Comment: I agree and tried to capture this sentiment with "To be overly precise:" I appreciate your comment. It helps me know how to best behave on this site.

Answer (score 0):

With $$B=\frac{\pi}{4}-A$$ we get
$$(1+\tan(A))(1+\cot(\frac{\pi}{4}+A))$$ and $$\cot(\frac{\pi}{4}+A)=\frac{\cot(A)-1}{1+\cot(A)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$A=45-B=\frac {\pi}{4}-B $$

$$\implies \tan (A)=\frac {1-\tan (B)}{1+\tan (B)} $$

since
$$\tan (\frac {\pi}{4})=1$$ and
$$\tan (a-b)=\frac {\tan (a)-\tan (b)}{1+\tan (a)\tan (b)} $$
thus

$$\tan (A)=\frac {2-(1+\tan (B))}{1+\tan (B)}=\frac {2}{1+\tan (B)}-1$$

Answer (score -1):

$A+B =45^\circ$

$\tan(A+B)=\tan(45^\circ)$

$\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B)} = 1$

$\tan(A)+\tan(B)=1-\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B)$

$\tan(A)+\tan(B)+1+\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B)=2$

$\tan(A)(1+\tan(B))+1(1+\tan(B))=2$

$(1+\tan(A))(1+\tan(B)) =2$

Answer (score -1):

Let $g = (1+tan (A))(1+tan (B))$ then we can expand to get $\dots$
$$(1+tan (A))(1+tan (B))= g = 1+tan(A)+tan(B)+tan(A)tan(B)$$
Now we turn to the trigonometric identity that states that $\dots$
$$tan(A+B) = \frac{tan(A)+tan(B)}{1-tan(A)tan(B)}$$
Now we take our expansion of $g$ and multiply by $-1$ and add $2$ resulting in $\dots$
$$-g+2= 1-tan(A)-tan(B)-tan(A)tan(B) $$$$ 2-g = -[tan(A) + tan(B)] + 1-tan(A)tan(B)$$
Dividing both sides by $1-tan(A)tan(B)$ we get $\dots $
$$\frac{2-g}{1-tan(A)tan(B)} = - \frac{tan(A)+tan(B)}{1-tan(A)tan(B)} 
+1$$
$$\frac{2-g}{1-tan(A)tan(B)} = 1-tan(A+B) = 1-tan(45) = 0 $$
$$2-g = 0$$
$$g=(1+tan (A))(1+tan (B)) = 2 $$